# Regex for IIS URL Rewrite from one domain to other domains based on parameter in URL

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I have a set of URLs which I would like to rewrite to other domains based on the value of an ID parameter in the URL:

http://sub.maindomain.com/community/12345678/etc
--> needs to rewrite to: http://sub.domain1.com/etc

http://sub.maindomain.com/community/44566336/etc
--> needs to rewrite to: http://sub.domain2.com/etc

http://sub.maindomain.com/community/8181881/etc
--> needs to rewrite to: http://sub.domain3.com/etc

I've found several posts explaining how to set up Rewrite rules, but none that matches the above scenario. Any ideas? Is it even doable?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 0):

We could use the `Path_Info` server variable to match the ID parameter in the URL segments. Please refer to the below code snippets.

```
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="MyRule" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="\/community\/([0-9]+)(.*)" />
                        </conditions>
<!--{C:1} is the value of id, {C:2} is the rest of the URL segment. it is referred by the above condition.-->
                        <action type="Redirect" url="http://{mymap:{C:1}}{C:2}" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
          <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="mymap" defaultValue="">
              <add key="12345678" value="www.bing.com"></add>
          <add key="44566336" value="www.microsoft.com"></add>
            </rewriteMap>
          </rewriteMaps>
            </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

See this link for more usages of the server variables.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.